# From Erlang to Python and function overloading in Python

Tags: python, erlang, overloading

Interestingly, do any of the users of stack overflow write in a functional paradigm or not?
I rewrite the program from erlang to python. I can’t understand how to do this, given that in python there is no function overload, which is so needed in this code. In general, in python there are not many convenient things that erlang has, for example, passing an empty list [] or a list of [Head | Tail] as function parameters.
I rewrote a bit, but I feel that this is a little like a functional style (except for recursion).
Maybe someone is ready to help me rewrite the code, or at least answer the questions that I asked above?

Erlang code:

```erlang
-module(dik).
-export([read_graph/1]).
-export([dijkstra/2]).
-export([start/0]).

% The file contains an adjacency list representation of an undirected weighted graph.
% Each row consists of the node tuples that are adjacent to that particular vertex along with the length of that edge.
% Returns a dictionary of VertexNumber -> [Edge]
%   Where Edge is {edge, {vertex, From}, {vertex, To}, Weight}
read_graph(FileName) ->
    {ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [read]),
    Nodes = dict:new(),
    parse_rows(Device, Nodes).

parse_rows(Device, Nodes) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, "") of
        eof -> Nodes;
        Line -> [VertexNumString | Row] = string:tokens(Line, " \t\n"),
                VertexNum = list_to_integer(VertexNumString),
                case dict:is_key(VertexNum, Nodes) of
                    false -> NewNodes = dict:store(VertexNum, [], Nodes)
                end,
                NewNodes2 = get_edges_from_line(NewNodes, VertexNum, Row),
                parse_rows(Device, NewNodes2)
    end.

parse_edge(Nodes, FromVertexNum, Val) ->
    [VertexString, WeightString] = string:tokens(Val, ","),
    [ToVertexNum, Weight] = [list_to_integer(VertexString), list_to_integer(WeightString)],
    dict:append(FromVertexNum, {edge, {vertex, FromVertexNum}, {vertex, ToVertexNum}, Weight}, Nodes).

get_edges_from_line(Nodes, _, []) -> 
    Nodes;

get_edges_from_line(Nodes, VertexNum, [Head | Tail]) -> 
    NewNodes = parse_edge(Nodes, VertexNum, Head),
    get_edges_from_line(NewNodes, VertexNum, Tail).


% Performs dijkstras shortest path algorithm on the given graph (Dictionary of VertexNumber -> [Edge]), starting at StartNode.
% Returns a Dictionary of VertexNumber -> Distance.
dijkstra(Nodes, StartNode) ->
    NewNodes = dict:map(fun(Key, Val) -> {if Key == StartNode -> 0; true -> infinity end, not_visited, Val} end, Nodes),
    dict:map(fun(_, {Distance, _, _}) -> Distance end, explore_nodes(NewNodes, StartNode, [StartNode])).


% Closest node returns the node with the lowest distance from the given list of nodes.
closest_node(Nodes, Unvisited) ->
    closest_node(Nodes, Unvisited, none, infinity).

closest_node(_, [], MinNode, _) ->
    MinNode;

closest_node(Nodes, [CurNode|Unvisited], MinNode, Distance) ->
    {CurDistance, Visited, _} = dict:fetch(CurNode, Nodes),
    % Note that any number is < any atom, so 43523452345 < infinity is true.
    if CurDistance < Distance andalso Visited == not_visited ->
        closest_node(Nodes, Unvisited, CurNode, CurDistance);
       true ->
        closest_node(Nodes, Unvisited, MinNode, Distance)
    end.

% Explore the given Nodes starting from NodeNum.
explore_nodes(Nodes, NodeNum, Unvisited) ->
    {NewNodes, NewUnvisited} = explore_node(Nodes, NodeNum, Unvisited),
    NextNode = closest_node(Nodes, NewUnvisited),
    if NextNode == none ->
        Nodes;
       true ->
        explore_nodes(NewNodes, NextNode, NewUnvisited)
    end.

% Convenience function to fetch node from dictionary so we can pattern match on whether it's been visited.
explore_node(Nodes, NodeNum, Unvisited) ->
    explore_node(Nodes, NodeNum, dict:fetch(NodeNum, Nodes), Unvisited).

% Already been visited: Do Nothing.
explore_node(Nodes, _, {_, visited, _}, Unvisited) ->
    {Nodes, Unvisited};

% Go through all the edges of the current node and update the tentative distance of the connected nodes.
% Add any unvisited nodes this node is connected to to the unvisited list.
explore_node(Nodes, NodeNum, {FromDistance, not_visited, [Edge|Edges]}, Unvisited) ->
    {edge, {vertex, NodeNum}, {vertex, ToVertexNum}, Weight} = Edge,
    {ToDistance, ToVisited, ToEdges} = dict:fetch(ToVertexNum, Nodes),
    if (ToDistance == infinity) orelse (Weight + FromDistance < ToDistance) ->
        NewNodes = dict:store(ToVertexNum, {Weight + FromDistance, ToVisited, ToEdges}, Nodes);
       true ->
        NewNodes = Nodes
    end,
    if ToVisited == not_visited ->
        NewUnvisited = [ToVertexNum | Unvisited];
       true ->
        NewUnvisited = Unvisited
    end,
    explore_node(NewNodes, NodeNum, {FromDistance, not_visited, Edges}, NewUnvisited);

% Out of edges, this node has now been visited.
explore_node(Nodes, NodeNum, {FromDistance, not_visited, []}, Unvisited) ->
    % We have looped through all the edges so we need another dictionary fetch to get them back.
    {FromDistance, not_visited, OriginalEdges} = dict:fetch(NodeNum, Nodes),
    % Mark as visited.
    {dict:store(NodeNum, {FromDistance, visited, OriginalEdges}, Nodes), Unvisited}.

% Get the distances of a few nodes from the example graph.
start() ->
    DistanceNodes = [7,37,59,82,99,115,133,165,188,197],
    lists:map(fun(NodeNum) -> dict:fetch(NodeNum, dijkstra(read_graph("dijkstraData.txt"), 1)) end, DistanceNodes).
```

What I wrote in python:

```py
def read_graph(FileName) -> dict:
    try:
        f, NewNodes = open(FileName), dict()
        return parse_rows(f, NewNodes)
    except FileNotFoundError as ex:
        print(ex)


def parse_rows(f, NewNodes) -> dict:
    Line = f.readline()
    if Line == '':
        return NewNodes
    else:
        test = Line.replace('\n', '').split('\t')
        VertexNum, Row = int(test.pop(0)), test
        if NewNodes.get(VertexNum) is None:
            NewNodes[VertexNum] = []
        get_edges_from_line(NewNodes, VertexNum, Row)
        return parse_rows(f, NewNodes)


def parse_edge(NewNodes, FromVertexNum, Val) -> dict:
    [VertexString, WeightString] = Val.split(',')
    [ToVertexNum, Weight] = [int(VertexString), int(WeightString)]
    return NewNodes.get(FromVertexNum).append((edge, (vertex, FromVertexNum), (vertex, ToVertexNum), Weight))


def get_edges_from_line(NewNodes, VertexNum, Snake) -> dict:
    if not Snake:
       return NewNodes
    Head, Tail = Snake.pop(0), Snake
    parse_edge(NewNodes, VertexNum, Head)
    return get_edges_from_line(NewNodes, VertexNum, Tail)
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking. As an side, *recursion* is a *core feature* of most functional programming (used in the place of iterative statements like for-loops or while loops). It is **almost certainly** better to learn Python on it's own terms, instead of trying to transliterate Erlang code with it's idioms into Python. Intead, you should write idiomatic Python. Or just stick to Erlang.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, my task is to rewrite the code, adhering to the functional paradigm. I constantly fall into the structural paradigm. Therefore, I ask for help.

Comment: Structural? In any case, you need to provide a *specific* question. Asking us to transliterate Erlang into Python is not on topic. Instead, you should ask a question like "how would I do <this specific thing>" in Python? And you should definitely do some research, because often, these questions have already been asked. You *can* write functional code in Python, but the language **is not designed for purely functional code**, it is an eminently imperative language. For-loops are a core construct.

Comment: Note, Python lists are not like Erlang lists, I'm going to assume. It *looks* like they should be *cons* lists, but Python lists are array lists. Most algorithms written for cons lists are going to be horribly inefficient if you use the array list. Note, I don't know what you mean by " passing an empty list [] or a list of [Head | Tail] as function parameters. " Of course you can pass an empty list as an argument. It *seems* like you are referring to pattern matching, which Python doesn't have (again, it isn't a functional programming language)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Of course, it’s not necessary to rewrite everything exactly. The problem is that this is the only code that I found that implements this algorithm in a functional paradigm.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, structural - I mean imperative

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Yes, pattern matching. I agree that this is not a functional programming language, but it supports this paradigm, so anyway, somehow, this code can be represented in a functional style, isn't it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, ok, do you have a functional dijkstra-style python algorithm? I don’t have, so I found the code in a functional language and try to rewrite it. I see no other way

Comment: Your task is to implement a functional version of disktra's algorithm in Python? Look, again, this is *way too broad* for stack overflow. You need to ask a *specific* question. You could ask about how to replace pattern-matching, for example (basically, it will involve `if-elif-else` on your function arguments). But asking us how to translate code from one language to another or how to do something from begiinnig to end is way too broad.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, about "you should ask a question like "how would I do <this specific thing>" in Python?", how would you do overloaded functions in Python? For example function get_edges_from_line - let's discuss.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, "Your task is to implement a functional version of disktra's algorithm in Python?" - Yes,it is my task. Well, I will ask more specifically or create a new question?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, don't write Python in Erlang and vice versa. Read the erlang code, understand it, then write it in Python in a pythonic way. They are different languages.

Comment: @Aus, I understand, but otherwise I didn’t succeed. I also tried translating imperative python code into python functional code and it also failed. I no longer know how to solve this problem, I did not write functionally before that.

Comment: Look, writing functional does not mean pattern matching or tail recursion (both doesn't exist in python, and pattern matching is not function overloading). Instead it means this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html However, that still means you have to re-think the erlang program, determine what it does, don't look at it, then write it in python as a python programmer. Any other way is a waste of time and bad practice in general.

Answer (score 1):

- For functional overloading, as you've discovered, it has to be done by hand with `if` statements and the like.
- As others have commented, the default `list` type in Python is an array, not a cons-based list, so using head and tail will be inefficient; lists are better handled using either `for` loops, or list comprehensions.
  `edges = [parse_edge(s) for s in snake]`
- If you do need the head and tail, they're: `nodes[0]` and `nodes[1:]`
- For the `parse_rows` function, it would be more idiomatic to have it accept the lines as an argument; reading input and parsing it are distinct pieces of work, so they should be in separate functions. This also makes it possible to write unit tests for the `parse_rows` function.
- If you like functional programming, you'll enjoy the [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (standard library) and the [more-itertools package](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io) (from pypi).
- Idiomatically, this code would probably use a class in Python; rather than passing around separate variables for `Nodes` and `Edges`, they would be attributes on a single `Graph` object. Most of the functions would then be methods (with `read_graph` a classmethod).
- The naming conventions in Python are snake_case identifiers for variables, functions and methods; CamelCase is used for class names.
- For functional paradigm, look at list comprehensions (and other comprehensions); avoid modifying variables in-place.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would mark the answer useful, but I do not have enough rating))

Comment: PS: for removing the trailing newline from input, probably `.strip()` is better; that strips leading and trailing whitespace of all kinds.

Comment: your opinion, is my code similar to a functional style or is it imperative yet?

Comment: In several places, you're passing around variables (dictionaries and lists) which are modified in-place; that's definitely not functional style.

Answer (score 0):

@Samuel 
Below snippet will highlight the issue of function overloading in Python.

In above, they have implemented decorator called overload. This is special case of decorators with arguments. These arguments to decorators are the key elements of function overloading since they specify the type and number of arguments.

Reference for more details
https://medium.com/practo-engineering/function-overloading-in-python-94a8b10d1e08